# Email Notification supported Javascript in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, html-email

Is there any way to inject javascript with Html in Editable email notification plugin or Jenkis?

Or how can we send html format with Javascript in email in Javascript?

Comment: Javascript is disabled on almost all emails. Limited functionality (like forms) are available in Gmail.

Comment: You should pratice firstly to write down a simple HTML and javascript in  `Default Content` in Editable email notification , then build job to send the mail to you, to see the javascript will be executed when you open and read it in mailbox. If it can, then it's worth you to spend time to find out solution.

Comment: Hello Yong I already tried in all the content types but nothing worked out!!!!